# How to migrate a collection whose document size is greater than 2MB from mongodb to cosmosDB

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm planning to migrate all collections from MongoDB to Azure cosmosDB. Since the maximum size of document in MongoDB is 16MB.

I have lot of documents whose size is greater than 2MB. But in cosmosDB, maximum document size is 2MB. So, while migrating from mongo to cosmos I'm facing storage size issues.

Is it possible to migrate the large documents ? If so..Can any one please suggest me the steps  to migrate the large documents from mongo to cosmos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to shred the documents into smaller sizes to store in Cosmos DB, then use a query to reassemble in your application which will require some rewriting.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark Brown. Will try this approach. While surfing internet have gone through Azure Blob . Can we use Azure Blob to store larger documents ? If so .. which approach will be the feasible way ?

Comment: You can do that and then use Cosmos to store meta data to query along with the URI for the blob. However the latency is not super awesome.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion Mark Brown.